# Django Models not being loaded when the celery worker starts

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celeryd

I am using Django-Celery 3.0.23.

When I run the command `python manage.py celery worker`, the models do not get loaded instantaneously.

This is something opposite as seen in `python manage.py celeryd`.

To test this I put a print statement in my `models.py`.

I read that `celeryd` is an older command for `celery worker`.

I am new in using django celery. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug/left-over in the app.

Follow up and solution here: [#253](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/253)